# Cache a HTTP GET REQUEST in Python Sockets

Tags: python, sockets, http, server

I'm making a proxy server using sockets. When the requested file is not in my current directory (cache), I do a http get request to the origin server (which is the www) and I cache it for later.

The problem with my code is that every time I get a resource from the www I cache it but the content of the file is always "Moved permanently".

So this is what happens: user requests "stackoverlflow.com" by entering "localhost:8080/stackoverflow.com" into the browser. The browser will return the page correctly. When the user enters "localhost:8080/stackoverflow.com" for a 2nd time in the browser, the browser will return a page saying that stackoverflow.com has moved permanently.

Here is the code of the method that does the http get request and the caching:

```
    @staticmethod
    def find_on_www(conn, requested_file):
        try:
            # Create a socket on the proxy server
            print 'Creating socket on proxy server'
            c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            host_name = requested_file.replace("www.","",1)
            print 'Host Name: ', host_name

            # Connect to the socket to port 80
            c.connect((host_name, 80))
            print 'Socket connected to port 80 of the host'

            # Create a temporary file on this socket and ask port 80
            # for the file requested by the client
            file_object = c.makefile('r', 0)
            file_object.write("GET " + "http://" + requested_file + " HTTP/1.0\n\n")

            # Read the response into buffer
            buff = file_object.readlines()

            # Create a new file in the cache for the requested file.
            # Also send the response in the buffer to client socket
            # and the corresponding file in the cache
            temp_file = open("./" + requested_file, "wb")
            for i in range(0, len(buff)):
                temp_file.write(buff[i])
                conn.send(buff[i])

            conn.close()
```

And here is the rest of my code, if anyone is interested:

```
import socket       # Socket programming
import signal       # To shut down server on ctrl+c
import time         # Current time
import os           # To get the last-modified
import mimetypes    # To guess the type of requested file
import sys          # To exit the program
from threading import Thread


def generate_header_lines(code, modified, length, mimetype):
        """ Generates the header lines for the response message """
        h = ''

        if code == 200:
            # Append status code
            h = 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n'
            # Append the date

            # Append the name of the server
            h += 'Server: Proxy-Server-Thomas\n'
            # Append the date of the last modification to the file
            h += 'Last-Modified: ' + modified + '\n'

        elif code == 404:
            # Append the status code
            h = 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\n'
            # Append the date
            h += 'Date: ' + time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()) + '\n'
            # Append the name of the web server
            h += 'Server: Web-Server-Thomas\n'

        # Append the length of the content
        h += 'Content-Length: ' + str(length) + '\n'
        # Append the type of the content
        h += 'Content-Type: ' + mimetype + '\n'
        # Append the connection closed - let the client know we close the connection
        h += 'Connection: close\n\n'

        return h


def get_mime_type(requested_file):
    # Get the file's mimetype and encoding
    try:
        (mimetype, encoding) = mimetypes.guess_type(requested_file, True)
        if not mimetype:
            print "Mimetype found: text/html"
            return 'text/html'
        else:
            print "Mimetype found: ", mimetype
            return mimetype

    except TypeError:
        print "Mimetype found: text/html"
        return 'text/html'


class WebServer:
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Constructor
        :return:
        """
        self.host = ''      # Host for the server
        self.port = 8000    # Port for the server

        # Create socket
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def start_server(self):
        """ Starts the server
        :return:
        """
        # Bind the socket to the host and port
        self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))

        print "Connection started on ", self.port

        # Start the main loop of the server - start handling clients
        self.main_loop()

    @staticmethod
    def shutdown():
        """ Shuts down the server """
        try:
            s.socket.close()
        except Exception as e:
            print "Something went wrong closing the socket: ", e

    def main_loop(self):
        """Main loop of the server"""
        while True:
            # Start listening
            self.socket.listen(1)

            # Wait for a client to connect
            client_socket, client_address = self.socket.accept()

            # Wait for a request from the client
            data = client_socket.recv(1024)

            t = Thread(target=self.handle_request, args=(client_socket, data))
            t.start()

            # # Handle the request from the client
            # self.handle_request(client_socket, data)

    def handle_request(self, conn, data):
        """ Handles a request from the client """
        # Decode the data
        string = bytes.decode(data)

        # Split the request
        requested_file = string.split(' ')
        # Get the method that is requested
        request_method = requested_file[0]

        if request_method == 'GET':
            # Get the part of the request that contains the name
            requested_file = requested_file[1]
            # Get the name of the file from the request
            requested_file = requested_file[1:]

            print "Searching for: ", requested_file

            try:
                # Open the file
                file_handler = open(requested_file, 'rb')
                # Get the content of the file
                response_content = file_handler.read()
                # Close the handler
                file_handler.close()

                # Get information about the file from the OS
                file_info = os.stat(requested_file)
                # Extract the last modified time from the information
                time_modified = time.ctime(file_info[8])
                # Get the time modified in seconds
                modified_seconds = os.path.getctime(requested_file)

                print "Current time: ", time.time()
                print "Modified: ", time_modified

                if (float(time.time()) - float(modified_seconds)) > 120:  # more than 2 minutes
                    print "Time outdated!"
                    #self.find_on_www(conn, requested_file)

                # Get the file's mimetype and encoding
                mimetype = get_mime_type(requested_file)

                print "Mimetype = ", mimetype

                # Create the correct header lines
                response_headers = generate_header_lines(200, time_modified, len(response_content), mimetype)

                # Create the response to the request
                server_response = response_headers.encode() + response_content

                # Send the response back to the client
                conn.send(server_response)

                # Close the connection
                conn.close()

            except IOError:  # Couldn't find the file in the cache - Go find file on www
                print "Error: " + requested_file + " not found in cache!"
                self.find_on_www(conn, requested_file)

    @staticmethod
    def find_on_www(conn, requested_file):
        try:
            # Create a socket on the proxy server
            print 'Creating socket on proxy server'
            c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

            host_name = requested_file.replace("www.","",1)
            print 'Host Name: ', host_name

            # Connect to the socket to port 80
            c.connect((host_name, 80))
            print 'Socket connected to port 80 of the host'

            # Create a temporary file on this socket and ask port 80
            # for the file requested by the client
            file_object = c.makefile('r', 0)
            file_object.write("GET " + "http://" + requested_file + " HTTP/1.0\n\n")

            # Read the response into buffer
            buff = file_object.readlines()

            # Create a new file in the cache for the requested file.
            # Also send the response in the buffer to client socket
            # and the corresponding file in the cache
            temp_file = open("./" + requested_file, "wb")
            for i in range(0, len(buff)):
                temp_file.write(buff[i])
                conn.send(buff[i])

            conn.close()

        except Exception as e:
            # Generate a body for the file - so we don't have an empty page
            response_content = "<html><body><p>Error 404: File not found</p></body></html>"

            # Generate the correct header lines
            response_headers = generate_header_lines(404, '', len(response_content), 'text/html')

             # Create the response to the request
            server_response = response_headers.encode() + response_content

            # Send the response back to the client
            conn.send(server_response)

            # Close the connection
            conn.close()


def shutdown_server(sig, dummy):
    """ Shuts down the server """

    # Shutdown the server
    s.shutdown()

    # exit the program
    sys.exit(1)

# Shut down on ctrl+c
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_server)

# Create a web server
s = WebServer()
# Start the server
s.start_server()
```

Comment: I could not get the same result when I try with Firefox 33. Instead on the second attempt to connect I am asked if I wish to download the page as it thinks it is a windows executable.   

This is caused because your code returns the mimetype based on the type of file which is determined by the extension, `.com` being a Windows Executable.

Comment: As you can see in my get_mime_type function, if the mimetypes library can't guess the mime type I'll just return 'text/html'. So .com will return 'text/html' and it should not think it's an executable. But maybe that's not the correct way to do this, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I would read the mimetype returned in the header of the request (given in `Content-Type:`) when you make to the actual web server, store that somewhere and then use that when you recreate the header when you return the version from the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when if you go to a page with that returns a status code of 301 page moved, it adds this to the header. When you view a page that is not stored in your cache, you copy the GET request that the proxy server makes straight to client. This will inform the client to make another GET request, which it makes ignoring your proxy server.

The second time you attempt to request the page through the proxy server, it retrieves the previous request from the cache. This file contains the headers from the previous request which correctly contain the redirect status code however you then add your own status code of 200 ok to the returned message. As the client reads this status code first it does not realise that you wish it to make another request to find the page that has been redirected. Therefore it just shows the page that tells you the page has moved.

What you need to do is parse the headers that are returned by the web server when the proxy server has to look at the actual page on the internet. Then depending on these server the correct headers back to the client.